# iOS - UITableView - Rows mysteriously repeating themselves when scrolling quickly? (simulator)

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I'm currently developing an iOS app using the Monotouch (Xamarin) framework.

I have a custom tableview source which uses custom cells, whose cell heights are calculated dynamically.

When I run the project in iOS simulator, if I scroll quickly to the bottom or to the top, the top cell replaces the bottom or vice versa - as if it were drawing incorrectly, or reusing the wrong cell by mistake?

Just to clarify - if my cells are

one
two
three
four
five

If i scroll quickly from top to bottom, my cells appear as

one
two
three
four
one

Or if I scroll slowly to the bottom, and the cells stay in order, once I scroll quickly to the top I'll get

five
two
three
four
five

And if I scroll up and down sporadically, the cells can mix up randomly.

My table source looks like:

```
    PostModel[] models;
    string cellIdentifier = "FeedCell";
    public FeedSource (PostModel[] items)
    {
        models = items;
    }
    public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
    {
        return models.Length;
    }

    public override float GetHeightForRow (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        FeedCell cell = this.GetCell (tableView, indexPath) as FeedCell;

        var height = cell.height;
        return height;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        FeedCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier) as FeedCell;
        //if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
        if (cell == null) {
            cell = new FeedCell (models [indexPath.Row], new NSString (cellIdentifier));
            cell.LayoutSubviews ();
        }
        //cell.height = cell.height;

        return cell;
    }
```

I've heard of performance issues with dynamic cell heights, but I'm only testing with 5 cells, and this just seems strange.

Could it just be my iOS simulator, and this wouldn't happen on the device? Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cells are reused whenever possible. The logic is give me any available cell (`DequeueReusableCell`), if no cell is available (`cell == null`), then create a new cell (`new FeedCell`).

Because of this, you should not pin the content of a cell when you create it. You just need to create a new empty cell.

After you have a cell, then you stuff the cell with the content needed at that index path.

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    FeedCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier) as FeedCell;
    //if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
    if (cell == null) {
        cell = new FeedCell (new NSString (cellIdentifier));
    }

    cell.model = models[indexPath.row]; // assuming you can do something like this.
    cell.layoutSubviews();

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Instead of initializing my cell as a reusable cell, I just initialized it normally and returned it, and that resolved the issue... but why is the content repeating and not just the size? Is it impossible to reuse cells with fully dynamic heights?

Comment: @JasonMcGraw I've done it in Objective-C. I can only assume it's possible in C#. The cell must be built to be resizeable.

Comment: @JasonMcGraw `GetHeightForRow` needs to determine the height of the cell independently from `GetCell`. The cell returned by `GetCell` must conform to the height returned by `GetHeightForRow`.